# Field is never assigned to, and will always have it's default value null

Tags: c#, oop

I'm using the following array in my code (Enrolment is one of my classes)

```
Enrolment[] enrolment;
```

I understand that the array is not initialized here, which would make sense for the error. However, the array is initialized in the following block of code.

```
public void AddStudent(Person studentName)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < enrolment.Length; i++)
            {
                if (RelevantCourse.CourseCode == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("This section has not been added to a course.");
                }
                else if (enrolment.Length == MaxNumberOfStudents)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Cannot add this student to section. Section is full.");
                }
            }
            int currentLength = enrolment.Length;
            enrolment[currentLength] = new Enrolment(SectionId, studentName, RelevantCourse.NoOfEvaluations);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

This block of code runs a try-catch block to see if there will be any errors with adding this `Enrolment` object to the `enrolment` array. The `enrolment` array shows an error stating that the "field is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null". When the code is compiled it obviously throws a null reference exception.

Why is its value null? Can someone direct me in the right direction to a solution here?

Comment: No, it's not initialized in the code you showed. There is no line `enrolment = new Enrolment[<somevalue>];` anywhere

Comment: Also the line `enrolment[currentLength] = new Enrolment` will *always* throw an Index out of bounds exception, you can't just increase the size of an array by writing past its last element (and `enrolment.Length` gives you the length of the array, not how many elements you have "written" to it)

Comment: You will get a `NullReferenceException` as soon as you try to access `.Length` in your `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialise the array

```
Enrollment[] enrollments = new Enrollment[{lengthofarray}];
```

You can't add stuff or get the properties of an uninitialised object that includes arrays